# Saltar mensaje de error cuando las columnas son distintas por filas

Tags: django, python-3.7

Estoy realizando un pre_action_validation, para que salte un mensaje de error cuando los valores de las mismas columnas de distintas filas seleccionadas tengan distinto valor.

Tengo 3 columnas en las que quiero que salte si son distintas, curiosamente si tengo en una fila todas con valor y la 2º fila todas con valor None -> me salta error (eso está bien). Pero si una columna tiene el mismo valor y en las demás columnas tienen valor y en la otra su valor es None -> entra en el formulario, pasa igual con un valor None; Y yo quiero que salte el mensaje de error.

Este es mi código:

```
def pre_action_validation(self, admin_class, request, queryset): #Error: SI 2 y 1 values en blanco y en la otra fila not null entra
    CHECK_VALOR = dict((('cliente', _('Distinto cliente')), ('tarifa', _('Distinta tarifa')), ('num', _('Distinto numero'))))
    ALERTA = dict((('precio_cliente', ('precio')), ('moneda', ('moneda'))))

    warning_messages, error_messages = [], []
    for mensaage_list, values_to_check in (
            (warning_messages, ALERTA.items()), (error_messages, CHECK_VALOR.items())):
        mismo_valor = queryset.values(*(v[0] for v in values_to_check))
        for value, msg in values_to_check:
            valor_list = [element[value] for element in mismo_valor]
            values_set = set(filter(lambda x: x is None, valor_list)).union(
                sorted(set(filter(None, valor_list))))
            if len(values_set) > 1:
                mensaage_list.append("{}: {}".format(msg, list(values_set)))

    for validation_messages, level in ((warning_messages, messages.WARNING), (error_messages, messages.ERROR)):
        if validation_messages:
            admin_class.message_user(request,
                                     mark_safe('<br/><br/>'.join([str(m) for m in validation_messages])),
                                     level)
    if error_messages:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el values_set hay que poner:

```
values_set = set(filter(lambda x: x is None, values_list)).union(
                    sorted(set(filter(None, values_list)))).union(
                    set(filter(lambda x: x == '', values_list))
                )
```

y en el formulario hay que ponerle un valor por defecto por ejemplo empty_value='-'

Comment: genial, lo he probado y está perfecto